# a col("Masse hydrique").divide(lit(100)) succeeds with Scala, but fails with Python, with a "'Column' object is not callable" error

Tags: python, apache-spark

I'm converting a Zeppelin notebook written is Scala into a Jupyter one, with Python

This piece of code is working with Scala:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DateType;

val poidsCsvFile = "/home/lebihan/correctionPoids.csv";
var poids = spark.read.format("csv")
    [...]
   .load(poidsCsvFile);
   
poids = poids.withColumn("pctMasseHydrique", round(col("Masse hydrique").divide(lit(100)), 3))
```

But what I believe to be its translation with Python:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

poidsCsvFile = "/home/lebihan/correctionPoids.csv";
poids = (spark.read.format("csv")
  [...]
  .load(poidsCsvFile))
   
poids = poids.withColumn("pctMasseHydrique", round(col("Masse hydrique").divide(lit(100)), 3))
```

fails with the error:

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

and it underlines the `col("Masse hydrique").divide(lit(100))` part of my statement.

I don't understand the message, and why the same statement could work in one environment and not on the other.

---

The full code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

poidsCsvFile = "/home/lebihan/dev/Java/garmin/correctionPoids.csv";

# 
# Durée,Poids,Variation,IMC,Masse grasse,Masse musculaire squelettique,Masse osseuse,Masse hydrique
# 11/02/2022,72.2,0.1,22.8,25.6,29.7,3.5,54.3
# 
poids = (spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")       # Détecter les types de champs
  .option("header", "true")            # Il y a des entêtes de colonnes 
  .option("quote", "\"")               # Les valeurs textes peuvent être entre guillemets
  .option("escape", "\"")              # Ne pas interpréter ce qu'il y a entre guillemets
  .option("dec", ".")                  # Le séparateur décimal (virgule française) est le point '.''
  .option("dateFormat", "dd/MM/yyyy")  # et les dates sont au format jour/mois/année
  .option("nullValue", "null")         # (pour éviter une mauvaise détection de type de champ sur une absence de valeur)
  .option("sep", ",")                  # Le séparateur entre champs csv est la virgule
  .load(poidsCsvFile))
   
poids = poids.withColumn("pctMasseHydrique", round(col("Masse hydrique").divide(lit(100)), 3)) \
   .withColumn("masseEau", round(col("Poids").multiply(col("pctMasseHydrique")), 1)) \
   .withColumn("poidsSansEau", round(col("Poids").minus(col("Poids").multiply(col("pctMasseHydrique"))), 1)) \
   .withColumn("pctMasseGrasse", round(col("Masse grasse").divide(lit(100)),3)) \
   .withColumn("masseGrasse", round(col("Poids").multiply(col("pctMasseGrasse")), 1)) \
   .withColumnRenamed("Poids", "poids") \
   .withColumnRenamed("Masse osseuse", "masseOsseuse") \
   .withColumnRenamed("Masse musculaire squelettique", "masseMusculaireSquelettique") \
   .withColumn("date", to_date(col("Durée"), "dd/MM/yyyy")) \
   .withColumn("ratioGraisse", round(col("masseGrasse").divide(col("poids")), 3)) \
   .withColumn("ratioGraisseSansEau", round(col("masseGrasse").divide(col("poidsSansEau")), 3)) \
   .withColumn("ratioMasseMusculaire", round(col("masseMusculaireSquelettique").divide(col("poids")), 3)) \
   .withColumn("ratioMasseOsseuse", round(col("masseOsseuse").divide(col("poids")), 3)) \
   .withColumnRenamed("Masse grasse", "masseGrasseKg") \
   .withColumnRenamed("Masse hydrique", "masseHydrique");
```

with csv content:

```
Durée,Poids,Variation,IMC,Masse grasse,Masse musculaire squelettique,Masse osseuse,Masse hydrique,
24/04/2022,70.1,0.0,22.1,24.3,29.1,3.5,55.2,
23/04/2022,70.1,0.1,22.1,24.5,29.1,3.5,55.1,
22/04/2022,70.0,0.1,22.1,25.3,29.1,3.4,54.5,
21/04/2022,69.9,0.0,22.1,24.8,29.0,3.4,54.9,
20/04/2022,69.9,0.4,22.1,24.3,29.0,3.5,55.2,
19/04/2022,70.3,0.1,22.2,23.9,29.1,3.5,55.5,
18/04/2022,70.4,0.4,22.2,24.5,29.2,3.5,55.1,
17/04/2022,70.8,0.8,22.3,24.7,29.3,3.5,54.9,
16/04/2022,70.0,0.3,22.1,24.4,29.1,3.5,55.2,
15/04/2022,69.7,0.3,22,24.7,29.0,3.4,55.0,
14/04/2022,70.0,0.2,22.1,24.9,29.1,3.4,54.9,
13/04/2022,70.2,0.3,22.2,24.9,29.1,3.4,54.8,
12/04/2022,70.5,0.4,22.3,24.7,29.2,3.5,55.0,
11/04/2022,70.9,0.5,22.4,25.4,29.3,3.5,54.5,
10/04/2022,70.4,0.2,22.2,25.4,29.2,3.4,54.5,
09/04/2022,70.6,0.6,22.3,25.3,29.2,3.4,54.5,
```

Comment: If `col` was still the [`pyspark.sql.functions.col`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.col.html#pyspark.sql.functions.col) function, it _would_ be callable. But at some point a [`Column`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.html#pyspark.sql.Column) object, which isn't callable, has been assigned to that name. Without a [mre] it's hard to suggest a fix - start by finding out what _is_ assigned to `col`, and where.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added the example. The `col` function isn't defined by the `from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit` statement?

Answer (score 0):

It means col has no function divide which you are trying to call. And if you look [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.try_divide.html#pyspark.sql.functions.try_divide) in the documentation, there is no divide function. Instead, it has try_divide.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, try_divide

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("division_example").getOrCreate()

# Sample data
data = [("Alice", 25, 5000), ("Bob", 30, 6000), ("Charlie", 35, 7000)]
columns = ["Name", "Age", "Salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
df.withColumn("div", try_divide(col("Salary"), lit(2))).show()

Output:
+-------+---+------+------+
|   Name|Age|Salary|   div|
+-------+---+------+------+
|  Alice| 25|  5000|2500.0|
|    Bob| 30|  6000|3000.0|
|Charlie| 35|  7000|3500.0|
+-------+---+------+------+
```

Or you could do:

```
 df.withColumn("div", col("Salary") / 2).show()
```

Comment: `try_divide` seems to be a spark 3.5.0 new function, but I'm still using spark 3.3. I will upgrade with Spark 3.5.1, awaiting some issue to be fixed. `divide` is a sql builtin function. You can see it called often, even here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.spark.sql.column.divide?view=spark-dotnet but I understand that Python may have renamed functions to avoid collisions with other of its functions

Comment: There is this div function for 3.3.1. You can try that: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/api/sql/#div

Answer (score 0):

Glad to your hints, Waqar Ahmed, I've found the solution.
`divide(...)`, `multiply(...)`, `minus(...)`, just aren't necessary with Python, and they don't exist:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

poidsCsvFile = "/home/lebihan/dev/Java/garmin/correctionPoids.csv";

# 
# Durée,Poids,Variation,IMC,Masse grasse,Masse musculaire squelettique,Masse osseuse,Masse hydrique
# 11/02/2022,72.2,0.1,22.8,25.6,29.7,3.5,54.3
# 
poids = (spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")       # Détecter les types de champs
  .option("header", "true")            # Il y a des entêtes de colonnes 
  .option("quote", "\"")               # Les valeurs textes peuvent être entre guillemets
  .option("escape", "\"")              # Ne pas interpréter ce qu'il y a entre guillemets
  .option("dec", ".")                  # Le séparateur décimal (virgule française) est le point '.''
  .option("dateFormat", "dd/MM/yyyy")  # et les dates sont au format jour/mois/année
  .option("nullValue", "null")         # (pour éviter une mauvaise détection de type de champ sur une absence de valeur)
  .option("sep", ",")                  # Le séparateur entre champs csv est la virgule
  .load(poidsCsvFile))
   
poids = poids.withColumn("pctMasseHydrique", round(col("Masse hydrique") / lit(100), 3)) \
   .withColumn("masseEau", round(col("Poids") * col("pctMasseHydrique"), 1)) \
   .withColumn("poidsSansEau", round(col("Poids") - (col("Poids") * col("pctMasseHydrique")), 1)) \
   .withColumn("pctMasseGrasse", round(col("Masse grasse") / lit(100),3)) \
   .withColumn("masseGrasse", round(col("Poids") * col("pctMasseGrasse"), 1)) \
   .withColumnRenamed("Poids", "poids") \
   .withColumnRenamed("Masse osseuse", "masseOsseuse") \
   .withColumnRenamed("Masse musculaire squelettique", "masseMusculaireSquelettique") \
   .withColumn("date", to_date(col("Durée"), "dd/MM/yyyy")) \
   .withColumn("ratioGraisse", round(col("masseGrasse") / col("poids"), 3)) \
   .withColumn("ratioGraisseSansEau", round(col("masseGrasse") / col("poidsSansEau"), 3)) \
   .withColumn("ratioMasseMusculaire", round(col("masseMusculaireSquelettique") / col("poids"), 3)) \
   .withColumn("ratioMasseOsseuse", round(col("masseOsseuse") / col("poids"), 3)) \
   .withColumnRenamed("Masse grasse", "masseGrasseKg") \
   .withColumnRenamed("Masse hydrique", "masseHydrique");

poids = poids.drop("Durée")
poids = poids.orderBy("date", ascending=False)

poids = poids.selectExpr("date", "poids", "Variation", "IMC", "masseGrasseKg",  \
    "masseMusculaireSquelettique", "masseOsseuse", "masseHydrique", "masseEau", "poidsSansEau",  \
     "pctMasseHydrique", "masseEau", "poidsSansEau", "pctMasseGrasse", "masseGrasse", \
     "ratioGraisse", "ratioGraisseSansEau", "ratioMasseMusculaire", "ratioMasseOsseuse")

poids.show()
```

is working.

```
+----------+-----+---------+----+-------------+---------------------------+------------+-------------+--------+------------+----------------+--------+------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|      date|poids|Variation| IMC|masseGrasseKg|masseMusculaireSquelettique|masseOsseuse|masseHydrique|masseEau|poidsSansEau|pctMasseHydrique|masseEau|poidsSansEau|pctMasseGrasse|masseGrasse|ratioGraisse|ratioGraisseSansEau|ratioMasseMusculaire|ratioMasseOsseuse|
+----------+-----+---------+----+-------------+---------------------------+------------+-------------+--------+------------+----------------+--------+------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|2023-11-27| 68.8|      0.1|21.7|         23.5|                       28.7|         3.4|         55.9|    38.5|        30.3|           0.559|    38.5|        30.3|         0.235|       16.2|       0.235|              0.535|               0.417|            0.049|
|2023-11-26| 68.2|      1.1|21.5|         24.5|                       28.5|         3.3|         55.1|    37.6|        30.6|           0.551|    37.6|        30.6|         0.245|       16.7|       0.245|              0.546|               0.418|            0.048|
|2023-11-25| 69.2|      1.7|21.9|         24.9|                       28.8|         3.3|         54.8|    37.9|        31.3|           0.548|    37.9|        31.3|         0.249|       17.2|       0.249|               0.55|               0.416|            0.048|
```